# Write a dict to a csv file on the right order

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dict like this :

```
{
'col1': [1, 2, 3],
'col2': [4, 5, 6],
'col3' : [7, 8, 9]
}
```

and I want a csv like

```
col1;col2;col3
1;4;7
2;5;8
3;6;9
```

I try with `for` loops but a don't succed to write the values in the right order.

Comment: Use an `ordereddict`, a `dict`s keys are inherently not ordered in the same order that the keys are constructed, or sort the keys and iterate over the keys to get the contents in the desired order

Answer (score 2):

Sth. like this should work:

```
import csv

d = {...}
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')

    header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    # header = sorted(d.keys()[, key=custom_order_fnc])
    rows = zip(*[d[col] for col in header])

    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: it give me an error message : `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to transform

```
data = {
'col1': [1, 2, 3],
'col2': [4, 5, 6],
'col3' : [7, 8, 9]
}
```

into a list of rows:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

We know that this expression will get a list of columns:

```
header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
[data[h] for h in header]  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

If we zip them together, then we will get what we want:

```
zip(*(data[h] for h in header))  # [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

With that, we can write the data to the CSV file. Putting it all together:

```
import csv

data = {
'col1': [1, 2, 3],
'col2': [4, 5, 6],
'col3' : [7, 8, 9]
}

header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
with open('dict_to_csv_in_order.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(zip(*(data[h] for h in header)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it will be super easy to write to csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': [4, 5, 6],
    'col3' : [7, 8, 9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.to_csv('csv_file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```