# change locations of dictionary key: value pairs according to the key names

Tags: python

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
{"par1_actual": 100, "par2_actual": 150, "par1_pred": 120, "par2_pred": 140}
```

how do I programmatically change the location of the key: value pairs that `par1` and `par2` will be  adjacent like this:

```
{"par1_actual": 100, "par1_pred": 120, "par2_actual": 150, "par2_pred": 140}
```

The reason for this needed order, is because I want to create a CSV from this dictionary in this certain order

I am looking for a generic solution that the names and number of parameters can change from one dictionary to another.
`_actual` and `_pred` will always appear at the tail of the parameters.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered structures by nature. While they do support insertion order from Python 3.7, I can't see why you would care about the order of the keys... Can you show an example of why this changes anything to you?

Comment: Note that the two dictionaries are still considered equal.

Comment: I care because I am writing the dictionary to a csv file and the order matters

Comment: Then *write to the CSV file* in a specific order. Of course, you could first create a new dictionary with the keys inserted in that order, and then write that dictionary to the CSV file, but it would be pointless.

Comment: so what you are saying, is that instead of changing the order in the dictionary, I can change it in the CSV  ?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to fit better your actual problem (and the answers given)? Right now the answers rely on comments and all details should be in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a dict to CSV in the correct order, try this solution which uses `pandas` from [Write a dict to a csv file on the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210577/write-a-dict-to-a-csv-file-on-the-right-order)

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"par1_actual": 100, "par2_actual": 150, "par1_pred": 120, "par2_pred": 140}

df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=['par1_actual', 'par1_pred', 'par2_actual', 'par2_pred'])
df.to_csv('csv_file.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to write the data to a file in a specific order (as mentioned in comments), you don't need to actually change the dict itself. Just manipulate the data.

If you know beforehand the set of "keys", you can iterate over them:

```py
names = ["par1", "par2"]

for name in names:
    for suffix in ("_actual", "_pred"):
        key = name + suffix
        file.write(key " : " + data[key])
```

If you don't know them and need to be generic, you can create the set:

```py
names = {key.split('_')[0] for key in data}
```

The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin collections module could be useful for your situation:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def sort_dict(dict):
    return OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))
```

Comment: From Python 3.7, the same can be done using a regular `dict` (please don't name your variables that)